# Can I use a binomial test in this situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, genetics

**A bit of context:**
Basically, I'm working with a list of genetic positions of interest (n = 358) which have, among them, a number of specific positions (n = 63) that are related to some genes (let's call them RBP).

**My problem:**
I'd like to know if, in the case of a random distribution of 358 positions along some part of the genome, the number of 63 positions in RBP detected is expected to appear by chance.

**What I've done:**
I randomly picked 358 positions and check by chance what it the number of time I found positions in the RPB genes. I repeated this step 1000 times and the number of occurrence looks like this:

[image]

I thought at first that this followed a poisson distribution but it is not the case (using a [dispersion test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809960/how-do-i-know-if-my-data-fit-a-poisson-distribution-using-r) found on Stack Overflow).

**My question:**

If it'd been a poisson distribution I'd have used the `ppois` function to determine the probability of getting 63 by chance. Since I can not, is it ok to calculate for each of the 1000 iterations performed before if the occurrence number is higher than 63 (which will result is a list of `TRUE` and `FALSE`) and them perform a binomial test (with prob = 50%) of the number success? If the test gives a significant result, it'd mean that the number of 63 is not obtained by chance. Do you think this is ok to do? if not, I'd be happy to hear any suggestion.